# choose from dropbox not working in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dropbox

I want to get file from dropbox account and save its preview link to my db.this code works fine in morzilla but not working at internet explorer.so plz suggest me:
jqueryCOde:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    var jQuery182 = jQuery.noConflict(); </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery182(function () {
        jQuery182("#db-chooser").live("DbxChooserSuccess", function (e) {

            var take = this.value;

            jQuery182(this).parent().find('.img').remove();
            jQuery182(this).parent().find("#hdField").val(take);
            jQuery182(this).parent().append("<a class='img' href='" + take + "'  target='_blank' >Image</a>");

        });
        jQuery182('.dropboxx').each(function () {
            var imagePath = jQuery182(this).parent().find("#hdField").val();
            if (imagePath.length > 0) {
                jQuery182(this).parent().append("<a class='img' href='" + imagePath + "' target='_blank' >Image</a>");
                (jQuery182(this).parent().find('div').addClass('dropbox-chooser-used'));

            }

        });

    });

    </script>
```

this is the html:

Answer (score 1):

Earlier versions of IE do not provide `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify` so you'll need a polyfill:

https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js

Answer (score 1):

Open the internet explorer with admin previliage.dropbox pop up menu is https and think ur site is http. And it doesnt return value from https to http. U can try with admin previlage